# Check if I has right: Is this the Extended Kalman Filter

Tags: noise, linear-systems, kalman-filters, non-linear, unscented-kalman-filter

I have learn the Kalman-Buncy filter for the LQG controllers. I know that this is a signal processing forum and not robotics not math forum. But Extended Kalman Filters are daily discussed here.

First of all! Let's say that I have model a nonlinear state space model:
$$ \dot{x} = f(x, u, t) + d(t) $$
$$ y_m = g(x, u, t) + n(t)$$

Where:

- $ \dot{x}$ is the derivative of the state vector of the system
- $x$ is the state vector of the system
- $u$ is the input signal vector
- $t$ is time
- $d(t)$ is the disturbance vector
- $f(x, t)$ is the standard form of nonlinear state space model
- $g(x, t)$ is the standard form of the output of a nonlinear state space model
- $n(t)$ is the noise vector
- $y_m$ is the measured output vector

My goal is to compute the Extended Kalman Filter gain $K$ fo the system so I can build my LQG controller.

Extended Kalman Filter uses jacobian linearizations to make the model $f(x, u, t)$ linear on equilibrium points.

So I build new linear state space matrix $A(t)$ and a output matrix $C(t)$ with respect to time. The linear state space model is:

$$ \dot{x} = Ax + Bx$$
$$ y = Cx + Du$$

But in this case I going to build:
$$\delta \dot{x} = A(t) \delta x + B(t) \delta u$$
$$\delta y = C(t) \delta x + D(t) \delta u $$

Where:

- $\delta x = x - x_0$
- $\delta y = u - u_0$

The $x_0$ and $u_0$ is the equilibrium point and $u$ is the input vector.

I linearize $f(x, u, t)$ and $g(x, u, t)$  and get:

$$A(t) = \left [ \frac{\partial f({x}, u, t)}{\partial {x}} \right ]_{x = \hat{x}}$$
 $$C(t) = \left [ \frac{\partial g({x}, u, t)}{\partial {x}} \right ]_{x = \hat{x}}$$

Where:

- $\hat{x}$ is the estimated state vector form the LQE-observer

And of course I get $B(t)$ matrix:
 $$B(t) = \left [ \frac{\partial f({x}, u, t)}{\partial {u}} \right ]_{x = u_0}$$

But to finding Extended Kalman Filter gain matrix $K$, matrix $B(t)$ is not important.

So now I have my LQE-observer:
$$\dot{\hat{x}} = f(\hat{x} , t) + K[y_m - g(\hat{x}, u, t)]$$

And I find the Extended Kalman Filter gain $K$ from this Riccati equation:

$$\dot{P} = A(t)P + PA^T(t) - PC^T(t) R^{-1}C(t)P + Q$$

Where:

- $\dot{P}$ representing the state estimation error covariance matrix derivative
- $P$ is the state estimation error covariance matrix
- $Q$ and $R$ is the weighing matrices

Solve $P$ from the Riccati equation and put in in here:

$$K = PC^T(t)R^{-1}$$

Now we have our Extended Kalman Filter gain $K$.

Now I just plug $K$ into my LQG controller diagram:

[image]

**Questions:**

1. So all I need to inclue more are linearizations with the jacobian matrix?
2. Have I done it right?
3. Which comes first, the linearizations or the estimations? I need the estimated vector $\hat{x}$ to get $K$ and I need $K$ to get $\hat{x}$.
4. Should $\dot{P} = 0$ when I solving the Riccati equation?

Comment: Very good! but, the **extended** Kalman filter applies the linearizations, then proceeds by building the **discrete** Kalman filter parameters and updates those parameters inside the filter loop in terms of current **states**. You seem to use the **continuous** matrices and parameters for gain computations, that's possibly for Kalman-Bucy filter ? Do you want to use a contintous filter or a discrete filter?

Comment: @Fat32 That means that I need to have a discrete nonlinear model? Building a discrete model from a linear model requires that I need to find the state transition matrix $\phi = e^{At} $

Comment: @Fat32 I think that I want to use contintous filter, even that I going to implement my LQG into an Arduino or Raspberry Pi. Because I don't like the discrete version. Contintous kalman filter works well in a microcontroller.

Comment: Ok then. Lets see the possible answers.

Comment: I don't even know why people want a discrete model? Is not contintous better when it comes to microcontrollers such as Arduino and Raspberry Pi? It's still possible to compute the next state $x$ by using this formula $x = x + \dot{x}*dt$ where $dt$ is the sampling time.

Comment: @Fat32 For example. ODE45 in MATLAB solves the contintous ODE-equation(s) by just a small steps simulation.

Comment: People like the discrete form because solving for $\dot{P}$ usually more work, particularly as the number of states grows.  There is a general recursion sometimes called the Hamiltonian Form but all the step size issues remain

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz But how do I get a nonlinear discrete state space model? It's easy to build a nonlinear model for contintous time, but convert that to discrete...I don't know. I have seen that people set $\dot{P} = 0$ when solving the kalman gain matrix $K$

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Ok. That was a good explanation of why people prefere the discrete insted of the contintous model. It's much easier to compute the kalman gain matrix.

Comment: When $\dot{P}$ is set to zero, they are looking for a steady state solution. I remember a homework problem where $P$ ping ponged between 2 values.  It drove me nuts

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz So I might need to find the $ \dot{x_{k+1}} = f(x_k, u_k)$ then?

Comment: I suggest you Google Zakai Equation. The EKF approximates the underlying problem by treating it like a Gaussian. The Zakai Equation is more general but according to a teacher I had who had Zakai as his advisor, has not been solved analytically

Comment: There are a lot of papers and books on EKF including higher order approximations an the Iterated Extended KF. Might be a lot on EKF based on Kalman Bucy but I am ignorant of it. I have my bias

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz So there is a difference between Kalman-Bucy filter and Kalman filter?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz If you see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Kalman_filter#Continuous-time_extended_Kalman_filter The Riccati equation is not used...why? I thought that Riccati equation is required to compute the kalman gain matrix $K$?

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Yes, 99% of my reference material is based on State Transition forms and most of my experiences has been specific to innovations. I've never actually implemented both and then compared. I would expect the same performance since both start from the same place. One difference is that the state transitions form support problems in econometrics that are intrinsically discrete time. They do not correspond to a continuous time problem.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz compute the state transition matrix is quite hard for a 6x6 A-matrix. I have try it in Matlab by the command >> expm(At) where t is a symbolic variable. I got a huge matrix back. Could not use it. If you look at the wikipedia link, is $K = 0$ when it comes to the initialization?

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz What happens if I implement a continuous EKF into a microcontroller? Will it work?

Comment: My guess in these circumstances is that Kalman came up with his solution and then someone noticed that Riccatti studied the form a few centuries ago, so there is a version for Filtering and a general form that Riccatti first studied so carefully look at the Wikipedia EKF article and you will find a Riccatti ran

Comment: @DanielMårtensson Yes getting the state transition can be difficult, even for the linear case. Sometime transforming to companion form works. You can try truncation of the power series and use a Pade approximation. For an implementation, the matrix consists of numbers not symbols.

Comment: @DanielMårtensson That is a question that only you will be able to answer. I don't see why it wouldn't

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz Thanks. Then I will use continuous EKF in my Arduino. Just because continuous  seems to be easier to do.  So which equation should I use, the Riccati equation highest above or from the wikipedia article? They are quite similar, but not exactly.

Comment: One more question.  If you look at the wikipedia link, is $K=0$ when it comes to the initialization?